# #value error using FIND

Tags: microsoft-excel, find

I am trying to create a formula that will pick up the value in a cell from the beginning up to immediately before the ".".

e.g.  Cell A2 is 1440.00.  In cell B2 my formula is =LEFT(A2,FIND(".",A2,1)).

Also, in a new spreadsheet the formula works, but once I edit the cell the #VALUE error message appears.

Comment: Try this one =LEFT(A2,FIND(".",TEXT(A2,"0.00"),1)-1)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use the result in formulas and all your column is numbers, try

```
=INT(A2)
```

It means the highest integer less than or equal to the number;
no need for `LEFT()` unless you have text also.

Comment: Now I have another dilemma.  How do you capture the contents in a cell but remove the decimal point and the last digit.  It also needs to remain a number.

e.g. 145.35.  I need to capture 145 and 3